# Electron IpcRendrer not sending data from Main to HTML

Tags: electron, ipc

I'm creating a WhatsApp client similar to WhatsAppWeb. I use IPC for communication between HTML and main using the following preload.js

```
const { ipcRenderer, contextBridge } = require("electron");


contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("api", {
    send: (channel, data) => {
        // whitelist channels
        let validChannels = ["toMain"];
        if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
            ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
        }
    },
    receive: (channel, func) => {
        let validChannels = ["fromMain"];
        if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
            ipcRenderer.on(channel, (_, ...args) => func(...args));
        }
    }
});
```

the following is main.js

```
const path = require("path");
const client = require("./src/client").instance;
const { app, ipcMain, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");

let win;
function createWindow() {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1280,
        height: 800,
        icon: path.join(__dirname, "views", "images", "logo.png"),
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            enableRemoteModule: false,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, "src", "preload.js"),
        }
    });

    win.maximize();
    win.loadFile(path.join("views", "login.html"));
    win.webContents.openDevTools();
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow();

    app.on("activate", () => {
        if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0)
            createWindow();
    });
});

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
    if (process.platform !== "darwin")
        app.quit();
});

client.addListner("qr", (url) => {
    // this works fine and logging the URL after page change using a console log prints a valid qrcode url
    if (!client.isReady()) {
        let logoFilePath = path.join(__dirname, "views", "images", "logo.png");
        win.webContents.send("fromMain", {
            event: "onQr",
            args: {
                url: url,
                logoFilePath: logoFilePath
            }
        });
    }
});

client.login();

ipcMain.on("toMain", (_, data) => {
    let { event, args } = data;
    switch (event) {
        case "logout":
            client.logout().then(() => client.login());
        default:
            break;
    }
});
```

I have 2 HTML pages login.html and index.html the following are screenshots to explain the sequence of the application.
[screenshot of login.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdYCF.png)
the following is the script tag in login.html that interacts with the main process.

```
<script>
    window.api.receive("fromMain", (data) => {
        let { event, args } = data;
        switch (event) {
            case "onQr":
                generateQrCode(args.url, args.logoFilePath);
                break;
            case "onReady":
                window.location.replace("index.html");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        };
    });
</script>
```

[screenshot of index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lyh1N.png)
the following is the script tag receiving and sending to the main process in login.html

```
$("#logoutBtn").click((event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.api.send("toMain", {
        event: "logout",
        args: {}
    });
    // I think the problem may be here on page redirection becuase
       it almost feels like the script doesn't run at all in login.html after being reloaded
    window.location.replace("login.html");
});
```

after pressing the logout button the login page is loaded normally and the backend process generates a qr code normally but the recieve function is never triggered again.
trying to check if send function is the main process is working by adding a console log in the preload recieve function gives the following result in the console.

```
// preload after modification
const { ipcRenderer, contextBridge } = require("electron");


contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("api", {
    send: (channel, data) => {
        // whitelist channels
        let validChannels = ["toMain"];
        if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
            ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
        }
    },
    receive: (channel, func) => {
        let validChannels = ["fromMain"];
        if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
            // the console logs works fine
            console.log(">>>>>>>>>>> recieving");
            console.log(func);
            // this line doesn't do anything in the second page load
            ipcRenderer.on(channel, (_, ...args) => {
                func(...args);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

[screenshot of console logs in login.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZ7DJ.png)
what I'm trying to achieve is that login loads again after logout the application sequence starts over however the login page doesn't recieve anything from the main process after being reloaded even though the recieve function was triggered successfully which leads me to suspect the problem is in the way I reload the page using window.location.replace

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and it has nothing to do with IPCRenderer or page reloading but rather a mistake on my part. I didn't update the client object in the main process to a new client, so the QR code was generated but never sent as the old client was in the ready state.

```
// new main.js
const path = require("path");
// import the class instead of an instance to be able to create an new object whenever user logs out
let WhatsAppClient = require("./src/client");
const { app, ipcMain, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");

let win;
function createWindow() {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1280,
        height: 800,
        icon: path.join(__dirname, "views", "images", "logo.png"),
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            enableRemoteModule: false,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, "src", "preload.js"),
        }
    });

    win.maximize();
    win.loadFile(path.join("views", "login.html"));
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow();

    app.on("activate", () => {
        if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0)
            createWindow();
    });
});

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
    if (process.platform !== "darwin")
        app.quit();
});

// moved listners to a setup function to call it when ever creating a new client
const setupClientListners = (client) => {
    client.addListner("qr", (url) => {
        // the problem was here as I were using the old client object which had a ready state of true so the qr was generate but never sent to the HTML page
        if (!client.isReady()) {
            let logoFilePath = path.join(__dirname, "views", "images", "logo.png");
            win.webContents.send("fromMain", {
                event: "onQr",
                args: {
                    url: url,
                    logoFilePath: logoFilePath
                }
            });
        }
    });

    client.addListner("ready", () => {
        client.isReady(true);
        win.webContents.send("fromMain", {
            event: "onReady",
            args: {}
        });
    });
};

// setting up client
let client = new WhatsAppClient();
setupClientListners(client);
client.login();

ipcMain.on("toMain", async (_, data) => {
    let { event, args } = data;
    switch (event) {
        case "logout":
            await client.logout();
            // delete old client and create a new one
            delete client;
            client = new WhatsAppClient();
            setupClientListners(client);
            client.login();
        default:
            break;
    }
});
```